# Robot Framework complains SWIG generated python file contains no keywords

Tags: swig, robotframework

I'm using SWIG to generate wrapper from C++ for Robot Framework as test library. RF issues a warning because it contains no keywords.

The system under test is a Win32 DLL, LibLogin2, created by VS wizard. It exports the function by default:

```
LIBLOGIN2_API int fnLibLogin2(void);

// This is an example of an exported function.
LIBLOGIN2_API int fnLibLogin2(void)
{
    return 42;
}
```

I add interface file to the project:

```
/* LibLogin2.i */
 %module LibLogin2
 %{
  extern int fnLibLogin2(void);
 %}

 extern int fnLibLogin2(void);
```

LibLogin2.py, LibLogin2_warp.cxx, _LibLogin2.pyd are built successfully with Release|x64.

I have a RF test case as follows:

```
*** Settings ***
Library LibLogin2.py


*** Test Case ***
Trivial
    ${value} =  fnLibLogin2
    Should Be Equal ${value}    ${42}
```

I launch Robot Framework and get THE error:

> pybot LoginTests.tsv
>   [ WARN ] Imported library 'LibLogin2.py' contains no keywords

I can work around this by commenting out the last line of LibLogin.py:

```
def fnLibLogin2():
  return _LibLogin2.fnLibLogin2()
#fnLibLogin2 = _LibLogin2.fnLibLogin2
```

It's annoying when you have to comment out every key word every time.

Please advice!

Here is my configuration:

Windows 8 64-bit 
Visual Studio 2012 
Python 2.6.6 
Robot Framework 2.7.5 
swigwin-2.0.8